# Error when trying to compile the program

Tags: java, io, filereader, filewriter

I'm trying to run this code taken from Sun Java site (I didn't copy it, Looked at it and wrote it as it would help me to remember the code).

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CharEx{
    FileReader inputStream = null;
        FileWriter outputStream = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        FileReader inputStream = null;
        FileWriter outputStream = null;

        try{
            inputStream = FileReader("xanadu.txt");
            outputStream = FileWriter("out.txt");
            int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1){
                outputStream(c);
            } 
        }
        finally{
            if(inputStream !=null){
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if(outputStream !=null){
                outputStream.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting follwing error.

```
D:\Java>javac CharEx.java
CharEx.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method FileReader(java.lang.String)
location: class CharEx
                        inputStream = FileReader("xanadu.txt");
                                      ^
CharEx.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method FileWriter(java.lang.String)
location: class CharEx
                        outputStream = FileWriter("out.txt");
                                       ^
CharEx.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method outputStream(int)
location: class CharEx
                                outputStream(c);
                                ^
3 errors
```

From the message I think that the system is looking for `FileReader` inside `java.lang` whereas it should look for it inside `java.io.*` :((

Can someone help me where I'm getting wrong?

PS: I'm on JDK 1.5.

Comment: I suggest you try using an IDE. It will help you write correct code and give you faster feed back.

Comment: @Peter: agreed. However there's also a lot to be said for learning to compile and runs things manually.

Comment: Partially off-topic: I would avoid calling a variable holding a `Reader` anything ending in `Stream`: `Reader`/`Writer` are for handling text and `InputStream`/`OutputStream` are for handling binary data. While both groups can be thought of as "streams" in a general sense, mixing terminology this way can be confusing. I'd call the variables "reader" and "writer" respectively.

Comment: @Richard, I agree there is alot of good things to learn. It depends on whether he wants to learn how to use the underlying tools or learn how to program first. ;)

Comment: Thanks peter for the suggestion. I knw this kind of silly mistakes can be avoided by using IDE but by using NOTEPAD and cmd prompt I'm learning more about the basics. This was highly recomended by my SCJP tutor to use NOTEPAD for examples.

Comment: note that your method signature for main is incorrect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate a  `FileReader` and a `FileWriter` (i.e. create objects of those types).

To do that you need to use the `new` keyword:

```
inputStream = new FileReader("xanadu.txt");
outputStream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
```

By leaving out the `new` the code looks like a method call, so the compiler looks for a method named `FileReader` (and `FileWriter`) and doesn't find it, which it tells you in a somewhat strange, but surprisingly clear language.

Hint: "symbol" is what a compiler calls a "name". That name can be of a class, method, variables, ... The exact problem can be found when checking the "symbol: "line. It tells you that the compiler looks for a **method** called `FileReader` that takes a `String` parameter:

```
CharEx.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method FileReader(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: You should also have outputStream.write(c) at line 18.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joachim & Bstick. I fixed the code. Joachim, That is a very insightful answer thanks a lot for your time. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `new` keyword when initializing the reader and writer.

```
inputStream = new FileReader("xanadu.txt");
outputStream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
```

You are also missing something on this line:

```
outputStream(c);
```

Do you want to write to the output stream there?  Then you should try this:

```
outputStream.write(c);
```